# While In-app purchase testing in google play i got an error " Error retrieving information from server [RPC:S-7:AEC-0]"

Tags: android

I want to test In-App purchase-v3 in my application. When i enter my credentials associated with the device then i submit my fake credit card info (Search from Google) and click on save button. I always got an error message "Error retrieving information from server [RPC:S-7:AEC-0]". Don't know why this is happening?

Comment: yes searched on Google and not found any satisfactory response. what I found that there is some problem with fake details of credit card or may be problem related with Google wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. We need to enter an original credit card details while enter credentials for inApp purchase. Google play will retrieve your information and you will eligible to purchase item, as your application is in testing mode so no amount will deduct from your account.